# Custom Authentication .Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a web app that allows a user to pay for a holiday booking.

The user will log in using a combination of a unique booking ID and a booking password.

Is there a simple way I can authenticate the user once they have successfully logged in. Is it a good idea to use the .net session object for this purpose?

The app wont be load balanced so I don't need to worry about storing session across different machines.

I would like to not have to use .Net membership as I don't want to create any extra tables in the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are able to retrieve the user, I guess this is possible. Below is the way I would try:

```
public ActionResult UrlAuth(string bookingId, string bookingPass)
{
    var userManager=HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();

    // Retrieve the user by the give booking values (Custom part in your app
    string userId= _bookingRepository.GetUserIdByBooking(bookingId, bookinggPass);

    var user = userManager.FindById(userId);
    if (user != null)
    {
        var userIdentity = userManager.CreateIdentity(user, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

        HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties { IsPersistent = false }, userIdentity );

        // authentication succeed do what you want 
        return Redirect("Wherever");
    }

    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid booking values");

    return View();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This helped a lot

Answer (score 1):

Here's a good general article with custom authentication for MVC

http://www.ryadel.com/en/http-basic-authentication-asp-net-mvc-using-custom-actionfilter/

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1005485/RESTful-Day-sharp-Security-in-Web-APIs-Basic